# Phpmyadmin displays the code instead of being interpreted

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

First, I would like to says, i searched for long time before to post and I know the topic has been discuss but, with older versions of what I'm using so, I don't know what to do.

My problem is, I installed lamp, on Ubuntu, and everything seemed to be well installed. But when I try to get to phpmyadmin, I get a php code displayed, like this :

```
<?php /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */ /** * Main loader script * * @package PhpMyAdmin ........ and so on...
```

Anybody knows what is happening, and can help, please?

EDIT : okay some 2016 posts says it is cause I don't have php5 installed, but I does en php -v and it says I have php7 installed. When I try to install php5 packages, it says no versions are avaible for me to install, hopoe it helps, really don't understand what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

Found this in another thread online, and it worked.

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2 

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```